# Command Line windows compiler (cl.exe) target

Tags: .net, c++, c, windows

In the .NET compiler (csc.exe) I can use the option `/target:exe` to compile into an exe that will keep the console open so that I can see some `stderr` or `stdout`` output. However I cannot achieve this same functionality using the C/C++ compiler (cl.exe).

My program uses `WinMain` which means it's an entire UI application. That's why I need to keep the console.

Comment: Well, create one.  Call AllocConsole().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the flag you need to create a console application is `/subsystem:console`, check out the MSDN documentation [about it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcc1zstk.aspx). and it is actually a flag for the linker stage:

```
link /out:foo.exe /subsystem:console a.obj b.obj
```

you can however tell the compiler to use certain flags when invoking the linker:

```
cl /flags /link /subsystem:console
```

since you need a `main()` to make the link work, provide a simple one that calles `WinMain()`

```
int main() { 
    return WinMain(0,0,0,0);
}
```

Comment: I forgot to specify that I'm using `WinMain` and therefore my app has a UI, it's not a simple command-line program. I get a linkage error with that flag: `LIBCMT.lib(crt0.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup main.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals`

Comment: Thanks. Adding a main function with WinMain call woks!